# Visual Studio Codeで.scssファイルを作成および保存する際に、複数の.cssファイルが自動的に生成されるのを防ぎたい

Tags: css, vscode, sass, compiler

VScode上でsassを使用したプロジェクトがあったため.scssに.cssから変更しコマンド＋Sで保存したところ以下のような複数の.cssファイルが生成されました。

##### 保存したファイル

- .global.scss

##### 自動生成されたファイル

- .global.css
- .global.css.map
- .global.min.css
- .global.min.css.map

原因として考えられるものとしてlive SASS compilerという拡張機能とeasy sassという拡張機能の機能があると思いアンインストールしVScodeを削除したものの直らず自動生成されてしまいます。

同じような事象が数ヶ月前にもありその際にはVScodeのsetting.jsonファイル、もしくはVscode上の複数の設定（チェックボックスなど）を変更し治った記憶があります。

何度も同じミスをしてしまい不甲斐ないですがこれで判明したら忘備録などとしどこかに記録を残そうと考えています。
同じような事象を解決したことがある方、解決方法がわかる方がいましたら是非回答よろしくお願いします。